# jQuery show element beside currently selected button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Each of my radio buttons is inside a `div`, and immediately beside the input (`radio`) I have some text in a span with the `CSS` set to display:none. Since I have multiple radio buttons I'm trying set the span to show for ONLY the span beside the radio button that's selected. Thoughts?

Here's what I have currently.

```
$('input:checked').next().show();
```

Here's my fiddle for the full quiz I'm trying to build

http://jsfiddle.net/YSSWL/96/

Feel free to critique the rest of my jquery, as I'm likely over complicating something. I don't have a ton of experience with `jquery` or `js` (working on it).

#### **Solution Edit:** As Chausser pointed out I can use

```
$('input:checked').parent().find('span').show();
```

to select the span nearest the parent of the selected input and apply .show();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
$('input:checked').parent().find('span').show();
```

I updated your html to use some consistent classes and fixed your reset function as well. For working code check:

http://jsfiddle.net/YSSWL/106/

Comment: Bingo. Was just about to post this as I altered the snippet from your previous post. Thanks :) Will post a separate revised fiddle.

Comment: check the updated fiddle for some improvements to your script as well

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this completely with CSS:

```
.incorrect .incor { display: inline; }
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/YSSWL/105/

Here is a better way to write this I think.  A bit more flexible.  Sorry I deleted a bunch of your stuff to make it clear what was going on.

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('click', '#radiochk1', function(){
        var checkedRadio = $('input[name="question1"]:checked');        

        $('.correct, .incorrect').removeClass('correct').removeClass('incorrect');

        if(checkedRadio.hasClass('rightAnswer')){
            checkedRadio.parent().find('span.answer').addClass('correct');
        }else{
            checkedRadio.parent().find('span.answer').addClass('incorrect');
        }
    });

    $(document).on('click', '#resetq1', function(){
        $('.correct, .incorrect').removeClass('correct').removeClass('incorrect');
        $('input[name="question1"]').attr('checked', false);
    });

});
```

HTML:

```
<form class="ra">
    <div class="cor">
        <input type="radio" name="question1" class="c1" />A. Choice A<span class="hiddencorr">Correct answer</span>

    </div>
    <div class="inc">
        <input type="radio" name="question1" class="i1" />B. <span class="answer">Choice B</span>
    </div>
    <div class="inc">
        <input type="radio" name="question1" class="i2 rightAnswer" />C. <span class="answer">Choice C</span>
    </div>
    <div class="inc">
        <input type="radio" name="question1" class="i3" />D. <span class="answer">Choice D</span>
    </div>
    <div class="inc">
        <input type="radio" name="question1" class="i4" />E. <span class="answer">Choice E</span>
    </div>
</form>
<p class="rationale1"><b>Rationale:</b> 
    <br />
    <br /><span class="rattext">Explanation of what was done wrong.</span>

 </p>
 <button id="radiochk1" class="checkhide">Check your answer</button>
 <button id="resetq1" class="reset">Reset</button>
```